# Save lists to re-open with Mathematica

Tags: export, import, fitting

I want to save a result of a computation in a file to re-open then in Mathematica in a new session.

What is the most efficient and simple way to do this?

To be specific, I am using  `NonlinearModelFit[]` and I want to save the resulting `FittedModel` in a file that I want to read just using Mathematica.

Comment: Do you want the fitted model to be the only information in the file you're saving? Otherwise, as far as I can tell, when you save a notebook in which a `FittedModel` is generated, the model and all of it's property information is saved and can be retrieved in the notebook when opened in a new session.

Comment: The question is already answered: Export["nmf0.mx", nmf0] and then
nmf1 = Import["nmf0.mx"]